# Unable to run Xunit unit tests on visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit

I am using visual studio 2017. I have a set of unit test that I have run and used before.

Right now when ever I run all of these tests using menu Test -> Run -> All Tests, nothing happens. Nothing is printed on Output windows, no error is thrown and everything stays the same. Even the project doesn't build like it before unit tests are run. Its like I haven't clicked anything at all. I can see all my tests on Test explorer window.

There is no code to show since its not a code issue.

What can be the reason behind this issue?

Comment: Do you see all the tests on the test explorer window?

Comment: @ArunSelin yes I can.

Comment: maybe some process is stuck : did you try rebooting your OS ?

Comment: @Mihaeru I am using XUnit. Everything is same, they used to run before.

Comment: Sometimes if the correct processor architecture(x86, amd64) is not chosen under test testing, such problems may arise.

Comment: Restarted visual stdio. They have all started to run now.